# Reactor Kafka: ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactive-kafka

I've just started using Reactor Kafka. I am wondering when and why use [ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/reactive/ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.html) over KafkaSender which is found in official reactor kafka reference guide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your choice; it's a wrapper around the `KafkaSender`.

Currently, the only real value add is the use of a `MessageConverter` which can convert a spring-messaging `Message<?>` to a `ProducerRecord`.

Comment: Thank you Gary. Would you please help me with my next question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304923/reactor-kafka-exactly-once-processing-sample

Comment: Hi @gary-russel, does the ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate also support consuming spring-messaging's Message<?> as a ConsumerRecord?

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in comments; this question was about the producer template. No; it is a lightweight wrapper around the `KafkaReceiver` only.